# While Integrating gitlab with the jenkins getting 404 Not found

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-plugins, gitlab-ci, git-webhooks

I am trying to integrate gitlab with the jenkins, i have configured following things:
a) Created a jenkins job added gitlab plugin
b) On the gitlab Added the url which is created by the gitlab plugin and the secret key
c) while testing i am getting this error:

Hook executed successfully but returned HTTP 404    Error 404 Not Found

### HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /project/test%20project%20iOS. Reason:

```
 Not Found
```

---

Answer (score 0):

1.Have you installed webhook plugin in jenkins?

2. Please make sure that you add correct  url something in this format
   <jenkins_url>/project/job_name

Comment: yes @Dashrath Mundkar i have gitlab webhook plugin and also using the same url which is given in the plugin itself